# How to make AFNetworking set a default image when the download fails?

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I want to do the following:

1. When the image is loading => Must display a spinner or another image indicating loading;
2. When the image is loaded => Must display the image;
3. When the image fails => Must display a static "no image available" image.

I tried:

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
   placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
```

But I couldn't figure out how to handle the failure event.

Comment: placeholderImage will be displayed incase of failure event.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I want another image to be displayed in case of failure. Not the one during loading.

Comment: pls look into SDWebImageView category, it has all the methods you need.

Comment: Please flag the correct answer when you feel it ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use

```
setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:
```

[From the doc](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit%2BAFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.h)

And set the wanted placeholder image in the fail block?

Example:

```
NSURLRequest * aURLRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"A-URL"]];
UIImageView * img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
__weak UIImageView* weakImg = img;
[img setImageWithURLRequest:aURLRequest
           placeholderImage:nil
                    success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                        //default
                    }
                    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                        weakImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fallbackImage"];
                    }];
```

Comment: And then I need to create the request manually. I thought there may be a simpler way :D

Comment: You can wrap it up with a utility method in an extension, or look for one of the many libraries around, but it's simple it doesn't really worth :)

Comment: Okay when I tried putting it into a helper method, and assigned a `no available image` to my image inside the failure block, I get this error: 
`Variable is not Assignable (missing _block type specifier)`

Comment: Yes there was a typo in the answer, sorry i am writing on the fly, i corrected the example and added some sugar. not sure it's the best approach, but should work.